# Not able to apply/revert the patch SUPEE-9767

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I have installed the patch supee-9767 in my server(it applied only for 2 files). So I try to revert the patch and apply it again. But I am getting the below error. Please anyone help me to fix the error.

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh: 14:
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh: 14:
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh: 25:
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.13.0.1_v2-2017-07-11-10-58-38.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file
app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogEvent/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/EventController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftWrapping/Model/Wrapping.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Model/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Model/Invitation.php
checking file
app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Helper/Form/Key.php
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #5 succeeded at 868 with fuzz 2 (offset 24 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Processor.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 394 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Symlink.php
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.3.1.1-1.6.0.3.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 344 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 622 (offset 2 lines).
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/head-simple.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/customerbalance/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/multishipping/payment.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/invitation/form.phtml
checking file
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/etc/config.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Enterprise_Invitation.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file js/varien/payment.js
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
checking file skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If patches not worked with sh file then try to apply patches manually. just download and upload all those files.

You can download patches from here and upload it via FTP.
https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-9767-without-ssh/

Hope above solution will work for you.